# How to fix? Discord.js Bot keeps going offline because of Value error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined
at Client.client.on.message 
(/home/colter/Code/groundskeeper/index.js:38:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle
```

I have checked for errors and compared it to the sample code. It all looks right to me.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) 
return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

// Here is my syntax for adding commands. So far simple ones, but commands non the less!
if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong');
}
else if (command === 'beep') {
    message.channel.send('Boop');
}
else if (command === 'server') {
    message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
}
else if (command === 'user-info') {
    message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}\nYour ID: ${message.author.id}`);
}
else if (command === 'args-info') {
    if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`Your didnt provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
    }
    else if (args[0] === 'foo') {
        return message.channel.send('bar');
    }
    message.channel.send(`first argument: ${args[0]}`);
}
else if (command === 'kick') {
    if (!message.mentions.user.size) {
        return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to kick them');
    }

    const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

    message.channel.send(`You wanted to kick: ${taggedUser}`);
}
});


client.login(token);
```

the expected output should be you need to tag a user in order to kick them from my bot when I use the ?kick command.

Answer (score 0):

On your code:

```
message.mentions.user.size
```

Is trying to read the property ***size*** of user, that is inside mentions, that is inside message.
If message, mentions and user don't exist, there's no ***size*** property to be read, you cannot read a property of something that does not exist.
You can check beforehand if it exists:

```
if(message.mentions.user) {
    if (!message.mentions.user.size) {
        return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to kick them');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 38, you have what appears to be a simple typographical error.

`user` (singular) is not a valid property of [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions). The correct property is `users` (plural), which you use correctly a few lines later.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this, if you only need to kick one person at a time.

```js
if(!message.guild) return; // Only runs if in a server
const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // This gets the first guild member, not user.
if (member && message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {  // Only tries to kick them if they exist and have permission
  try {
    member.kick(args.slice(1).join(' '); // Gives reason, if any and kicks them.
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
} else {
  message.channel.send(`You tried to kick: ${args[0]}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this for `kick` command!

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  // the cmd  >>        if (message.content.startsWith("{prefix}kick")) {
  //permission set to kick members only >>    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send // not enough perms message >("this bot Found An Error! Error: You Do Not Have Kick Members Permission!")
  // >> this is used to define @mentions    const member = message.mentions.members.first()
  if (!member) {
    return message
      .reply
      // A User didnt mention someone so thy get this error>>      (`the bot Found An Error! Error: A User Was Not Mentioned!`)
      ();
  }
  // if the bots role doesnt have their role above the user>>  if (!member.kickable) {
  return message.reply(
    `bot Found An Error! Error: Permission Is Not Above The User, Try Again When This Is Fixed!`
  );

  return (
    member
      // >> sucess kick message    .kick()
      .then(() => message.reply(`bot Kicked ${member.user.tag} Sucessfully!`))
  );
  // error bot message >>     .catch(error => message.reply('Error!  Please Try Again!`))
});
```

Comment: What?? OP asked why they were getting an error, not for people to make them a *new* kick command. Also, what's with the condescending remarks?